# Memory problems trying to convert a large csv file to a raster layer using R

Tags: r, csv, matrix, raster, r-raster

I have a large CSV file representation of a geographic raster map - 42011 columns by 18510 rows, around 10GB on disk. The file was created as the output of a convolution using the FFT function, which involved breaking the original raster into six strips, processing each and appending the resulting matrix to the csv file using the overlap-add method.

I am now trying to write the results back to a raster file type (e.g. ESRI bil, GeoTIFF etc) using the R package  [raster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html). Each number in the CSV file maps to the equivalent cell of the raster.

The obvious way to do this in R is:

```
library(raster)
library(data.table)
data <- fread("data.csv")                                  ## Read in data (as data.table)
data_mat <- data.matrix(data)                              ## Convert to matrix 
data_raster <- raster(data_mat, template=existing_raster)  ## Write to raster using existing layer as template
```

However, my PC runs out of memory at the stage of trying to create the matrix:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 5.8 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In matrix(if (intOK) NA_integer_ else NA_real_, nrow = d[1L], ncol = d[2L],  :
   Reached total allocation of 16108Mb: see help(memory.size)
etc
```

The computer is running 64-bit R with 16GB of RAM.

Things I've tried so far include:

- **bigmemory** - this looked promising, as the raster function can take a big.matrix as it's input, but the package is not currently available for windows.
- **ff** - I haven't fully grasped the capabilities of this package so far, but at present I can't see a way to get from the data.table to an ff object, and I'm not sure there would then be a way to get from that to a raster layer.
- **Sparse matrices** (using package "Matrix") - the CSV is probably more than 50% 0s. However, I can't currently work out a way to read it from disk as a sparse matrix, or to get it from a data.table into a sparse matrix. Whether I would then be able to get to a raster, I have no idea.

I am most familiar with R, but also have a working knowledge of Python and access to ArcGIS. I'm not sure if the question is better here or on gis.stackexchange, but it seems like primarily a programming problem. Any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: Try finding a similar function in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Big matrices have always been problems in R. I'm not familiar with geographic raster map. But is it possible to partition your data frame to pieces and generate matrices in a way that does not lose information?
"ff" packages could be of help. I found a related tutorial here, it shows a lot of examples of using "ff" package for large object. Specifically, page 20, "working with array and matrices", hopefully it helps.[ff packages examples](http://ff.r-forge.r-project.org/bit&ff2.1-2_WU_Vienna2010.pdf)